# Using buttons in WinForms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a WinForms application, which contains 2 buttons- button1 (RIGHT) and button2 (Left - which is not contained in the code below but is 98% same code). I have a picture and description of a movie, and when I press right or left I want to show another movie.

When I start the application, I need to press the right button twice to change the movie, but afterwards it works well. If I press the left button after I press the right button, it will show the first movie; but it's supposed to be when I press the right button. If I press the left button again, it works well.

Can someone explain me why is this happening and is not working well all the time?

Thank you.

```
        int id = k;
        int maxf = 0;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Count(Id) FROM Filme ";
        drr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (drr.Read())
        {
            maxf = int.Parse(drr.GetValue(0).ToString());
        }
        con.Close();
        if (k == maxf)
        {
            k = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            ++k;
        }
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Descriere FROM Filme WHERE Id=@Id";
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Id", id));
        drr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (drr.Read())
        {
            textBox1.Text = drr.GetValue(0).ToString();
        }
        con.Close();
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Imagine FROM Filme WHERE Id=@Id";
        //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Id", id));
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        SqlCommandBuilder bd = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        byte[] a = (byte[])(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Imagine"]);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(a);
        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        ms.Close();
```

Comment: What is a WFA?  Windows Forms Application?  I've never seen it abbreviated like that.

Comment: use your debugger and set break points also when assigning the images null out it's reference prior to reassigning it to `pictureBox2.Image` make that `pictureBox2.Image = null` and null out `byte[] a` after you close the ms. also try `ms.Flush()` see if that helps also show the EventHandler for the code below.. also what if drr.HasRows = false? you need to return

Comment: Yes I said WFA cause I met this abbreviation before and tought there will be no misunderstanding @Bradley  and I've also tried what you say @MethodMan and it`s not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `k` is your current image index and at some point when your application starts you initialize it with 1 and you look for movie info with Id = 1, the first time you click right...

```
int id = k;
int maxf = 0;
```

after these lines,

> k = 1
>
> id = 1
>
> maxf = 0

```
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Count(Id) FROM Filme ";
drr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (drr.Read())
{
    maxf = int.Parse(drr.GetValue(0).ToString());
}
con.Close();
if (k == maxf)
{
    k = 1;
}
else
{
    ++k;
}
```

After this piece of code,

> k = 2
>
> id = 1
>
> maxf = 5

Now, this is the part where you look for the movie info in your database...

```
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Descriere FROM Filme WHERE Id=@Id";
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Id", id));
drr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (drr.Read())
{
    textBox1.Text = drr.GetValue(0).ToString();
}
con.Close();
con.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Imagine FROM Filme WHERE Id=@Id";
```

You're looking for records with the same Id as your `id` variable, which currently has 1. You're retrieving the same record you had when you opened your application. The next time you click your right button, this happens:

```
int id = k;
int maxf = 0;
```

> k = 2
>
> id = 2
>
> maxf = 0

**NOW** id has 2, and your query will retrieve movie info with id = 2. That's why you need a second click to change your movie.

Solution: either look for movie info with `Id = k` instead of `Id = id`, or assign `Id = k` after you increase/reset `k`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I tought would be something more complicated than that and I should have been looking what values have k and id but thank you very much now it works well :D